# Typescript Electron types conflict with Dom types

Tags: typescript, electron, typescript-typings

I have an interface `FileWithPath` that extends `File` from `lib.dom.d.ts`

```
export interface FileWithPath extends File {
    readonly path?: string;
}
```

When using this in a standalone library this works fine and correctly resolves the type from `lib.dom.d.ts`:

```
/** Provides information about files and allows JavaScript in a web page to access their content. */
interface File extends Blob {
    readonly lastModified: number;
    readonly name: string;
}
```

However, electron has a conflicting `File` type:

```
interface File {
 /**
  * The real path to the file on the users filesystem
  */
  path: string;
}
```

When I use my library alongside an electron project it incorrectly resolves the electron type and gives an error:
`Interface 'FileWithPath' incorrectly extends interface 'File'.
  Property 'path' is optional in type 'FileWithPath' but required in type 'File'`

Is there any change I can make in the library to correctly specify that I want to extend the `File` from lib.dom rather than electron?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can add this options to tsconfig.json to igonre this error:

```
{
    compilerOptions: {
        skipLibCheck: true
    }
}
```